# How to mimic Bash redirection in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, bash

Say I want to execute this Bash command:

```
ls -ltra > somefile.txt
```

in Python:

```
subprocess.run(["ls", "-ltra", ">", "somefile.txt"], check = True)
```

The above returns an error. I know now it is the bash redirection operator.
How should this be handle in *Python3*+? Should run be used at all?

If I wanted to run this Bash command:

```
ls -ltra > somefile.txt 2>&1
```

Would solution change much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirection operator is how you tell the shell to open `somefile.txt` for writing, and to use the resulting file as standard output for `ls`. You can do this in pure Python:

```
with open("somefile.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(["ls", "-ltra"], stdout=f, check=True)
```

If you want to use the same file for standard error, use

```
with open("somefile.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(["ls", "-ltra"], stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, check=True)
```

You can also tell `subprocess.run` to use a shell to process the command line

```
subprocess.run("ls -ltra > somefile.txt", check=True)
```

though I don't recommend that for more complicated commands.